# React Native - Component UI getting blocked after rerender

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have two components that share a state through redux useSelector ().

CalendarDateList (with VirtualizedList) and Menu. In the Menu I have some buttons that change a seasonFilter status. This seasonFilter is used within the CalendarDateList to filter the array of the list. The problem is: when the button is pressed, the state changes and consequently the CalendarDateList rerender occurs, but this blocks the button's UI taking a long time so that it has the opacity of "pressed".

Is there any configuration to set the filter option of the other component's array without blocking the menu UI?

Basically I set through an action the seasonFilter on a Menu component and then access it on another List Component. When I hit the menu button, it blocks the UI thread stopping any animation from the TouchableOpacity button, for example. The UI is released only after the Calendar List is totally rendered.

```
export default function NavbarItem({ icon, text }) {
const seasonFilter = useSelector(state => state.seasonFilter);

const dispatch = useDispatch();

function toggleFilter(season) {
    let seasonFilterTmp = seasonFilter.slice();
    const seasonIndex = seasonFilter.indexOf(season);

    seasonIndex === -1 ? seasonFilterTmp.push(season) : seasonFilterTmp.splice(seasonIndex, 1);
    dispatch({ type: 'SET_FILTER', seasonFilter: seasonFilterTmp });
};
...
function CalendarTimeline() {
const calendarDates = useSelector(state => state.calendarDates);
const seasonFilter = useSelector(state => state.seasonFilter);
const filteredCalendarDates = calendarDates.filter(calendarDate => seasonFilter.includes(calendarDate.season))

return (
    <Container >
        <VirtualizedList
...
```

Comment: Sounds like a problem with how you access data, but hard to say without code, could you maybe update the question with any code that would help understand your problem better?

Comment: I just updated the question with a portion of code!

Comment: filter logic should be in redux (dispatch SET_FILTER with season) ... `filteredCalendarDates` is derived from state, should be calculated in `useSelector()` .... calculations are heavy ... delay `toggleFilter()`/dispatch with timeout  to be run after animation/menu close or manage state/changes locally, send actions (array of action objects) after `apply filters` button (with delay, too)

Comment: putting the logic inside redux and making the calculation in useSelector were good things..thanks, but if i add a delay, if the user hits multiple times, it will block too since it will stack multiple touches, and since its a toggle, i cant cancel the last touch...

Comment: use some 'debounce' ... toggles as props in object / defined/undefined - the same as filter/push in array